# Remove "powered by PrestaShop" link on facebook

Tags: facebook, share, prestashop-1.6

I work with prestashop 1.6.0.11.

I finished my shop and I wanted to share on Facebook by typing the address of my website, just to the right of the thumbnail there said "shop powered by prestashop" in black I want to know How can I remove?
  I am going to seo / url to change the meta description of the index but in vain.
if someone would help me ;)

thank you

Comment: In the PrestaShop forums there are lots of posts on this topic

Comment: Yes I know that there are several posts on this topic but the solution does not exist. I tried everything but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

1. Modules -> CMS Block.
2. Unset `Display "Powered by PrestaShop" in the footer`.
3. Save.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the Meta-description

1. go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing
2. type your site URL and click "Debug"
3. and than later click "Scrape Again button"

Answer (score 0):

After changing the index, Disable "Friendly URL" in SEO, save, and the you can re-enable it. Done.